# .NETFramework4.6.1 reference a classlib targetting .NETstandard2.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version, .net-standard

I create an asp.net webapp with Target framework: `.NET Framework 4.6.1`
and a classlibrary with Target framework: [`.NET Standard 2.0`](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/NETStandard.Library) in VS2017.
I would hope it would work fine as the [document](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md) says there are compatable:
[image]
but I got an error:

> Project 'c:\users\ConfusedDev\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.

what am I missing for this solution to build?

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/NETStandard.Library

The package you have used contains some sort of a stub for .net standard v2:

> ```
>   <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
>     <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" />
>     <dependency id="Microsoft.Packaging.Tools" version="1.0.0-preview2-25303-01" />
>   </group>
> ```

Which just directs to .NET Core. Though, you might try the lower versions of .net standard. They seem to be declared correctly in 2.0.0-preview2-25303-01 package.

Comment: `2.0.0-preview2-25303-01` is the package that I am using, are you saying that this package has the correct declaration?

Comment: I meant that while you are using 2.0.0-preview2-25303-01 you should try to opt for lower versions of .net standard <=1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when using VS 2017. I added some .Net standard class Library projects in a .Net 4.6 target solution. So I couldn't build the solution.

I added the corresponding number .Net framework Class Library projects. Then I cut and paste all the classes in the corresponding new projects (.Net framework) and deleted all the incriminated projects (.Net standard framework) and build the solution.